# Solving equations with logarithmic exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need to solve the equation :
$\ln(x+2)+\ln(5)=\lg(2x+8)$

With the change of base formula we can turn this into:
$\ln(x+2)+\ln(5)=\frac{\ln(2x+8)}{\ln(10)}$

We can also simplify the LHS with the product rule so: 
$\ln(5(x+2))=\frac{\ln(2x+8)}{\ln(10)}$

Solving the fraction gives us: $\ln(10) \, \ln(5(x+2)) = \ln(2x+8)$

Simplifying the LHS even further:
$\ln(5x+10)^{\ln(10)}=\ln(2x+8)$

We can then see that $(5x+10)^{\ln(10)}=2x+8$

And this is where I get stuck, I can't seem to figure out how to expand this term. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What makes you think that it can be solved analytically?

Comment: It's quite possible there's a mistake in the problem.  I don't think you'll be able to solve that for an exact answer.

Comment: What is $lg(x)$?

Comment: @voyska I've seen $\lg x$ represent a logarithm of base $2$.  However, in this case, it appears to be an error edited in by someone else.  The original problem before edits had $\log(2x+8)$.  And the OP's work treated it as a common logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer by researching of graphic of functions,I don't think you can get it by algebric method[image]